# Difference between (answer, index) and answer, key

Tags: vue.js, loops, iteration, vuejs3, v-for

Is there any difference between those two v-for approaches? One is (answer, index) and one is answer, key. Both of them work, however, the key one shows a red underscore in PHPStorm.

```
  <label v-for="(answer, index) in questions[questionIndex]['answers']" :for="index">
    <input type="radio" :id="index"/> {{ answer }}
  </label>
```

```
  <label v-for="answer, key in questions[questionIndex]['answers']" :for="key">
    <input type="radio" :id="key"/> {{ answer }}
  </label>
```

This is my setup

```
const questions = ref([
  {
    question: 'Question 1',
    answers: [
      "Answer 1",
      "Answer 2",
      "Answer 3",
      "Answer 4"
    ],
  },
  {
    question: 'Question 2',
    answers: [
      "Answer 1",
      "Answer 2",
      "Answer 3",
      "Answer 4"
    ],
  },
])

  [PHPStorm error][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/drT7X.png
```

Comment: The first one is the correct one.

Comment: add brackets (ie, `(answer, key)`) in the second one and it should work